# Jquery works clearly Firefox, but not in Chrome and Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have simple jquery code on my page  for show and hide two panels. it works clearly Firefox, but not in Chrome and Explorer.

when i click "Next" button later "Back" button, All the design of the page is distorted .

And i added "show alert" button. When alert is show page is distorted again.

```
$(function() {

      $("#button").click( function()
           {
             alert('button clicked');
           }
      );
});
```

plaese refer problems link: http://bit.ly/1v982qc

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#adm2").hide();
        $("#adm3").hide();
    });

    $('#button1').click(function () {

        if ($('#year1').prop('checked') == false && $('#year2').prop('checked') == false) { }
        else {
            $('#adm1').hide(); $('#adm2').show()

            if ($('#year1').prop('checked')) {
                $("#ruckpanel").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#ruckpanel").hide();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thank You!

INITIAL - From start the page look like this:

[image]

---

1. After clicking "Next" button it looks like this:

[image]

---

2. After clicking "Back" button it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I see no problems on this website (running Chrome 37, Win7 & OSX 10.9). The next & back buttons work as expected too.
Could be a little more specific in the issue? Maybe you post a screenshot?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Steps to recreate error. Click Next button, Click Back button, BOOOM

Comment: The featured images part doesn't appear properly when going 'Back'. That's what I'm seeing on my Chrome 37, Win7)

Comment: Yes, its problem, click "next" button, click back button and boom! :(

Comment: Wow... What a mess :) Your example code does not match that website though (which has loads of `onclick` attributes doing the work). Can you provide a better example of the actual code?

Comment: When I save the relevant section of that website to a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3fv8nska/, it appears to show multiple `Next` buttons. Can you check that over first?

Comment: **Immediate advice:** rip all the code in the `onclick=` attributes out of that page and connect the events via jQuery. I have spotted that some of your `onclick` handlers are simply showing/hiding *the wrong divs*!

Comment: @Pixic: Thanks. I removed your comment with the images. Please re-add it as a comment here instead.

Comment: As you can see in the last screen shot I provided (now included in the question), you are reloading the complete page within the page when going back. The back function is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple errors, but this is too big for a comment:

The click handlers in one block look like this:

```
        <span class="pull-left"><div style="width:100px">   <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block"  onclick="$('#adm3').hide();$('#adm2').show();"> Back <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-lg"> </i></button></div></span>
        <span class="pull-right"><div style="width:150px">   <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  onclick="$('#adm2').hide();$('#adm3').show();">Next <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"> </i> </button></div></span>
```

i.e. the relevant part looks like:

```
onclick="$('#adm3').hide();$('#adm2').show();"> Back <
onclick="$('#adm2').hide();$('#adm3').show();">Next <
```

That first one should probably be:

```
onclick="$('#adm2').hide();$('#adm1').show();"> Back <
```

as it makes no sense to hide the next page and show the current one!

### Suggestion:

I imagine there are many other maintenance problems in this type of coding, so I strongly suggest you unload the gun you have pointed at your own head and *stop using `onclick=` attributes for event handlers*! Use jQuery instead for all of them as per your example (you obviously know how to use them that way).

once your code is all in one place error like that will become obvious and you will spot much simpler ways to code the page behavior.

Comment: i added "show alert" button. When alert is show page is distorted again. Just simply alert but giving problem again.